# PyCharme IDE problems

Tags: pycharm

I can't open my PyCharm IDE.
Message error is `System path '/Users/pierrebordas/Library/Caches/PyCharm2018.1' is invalid.`
If you have modified the 'idea.system.path' property please make sure it is correct, otherwise please re-install the IDE"

I all ready tried to re-install, nothing happens,
and i didn't find the directory PyCharm2018.1 in `~/Library/Caches`. Has someone already had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pierre,

I was able to reproduce this issue by each of:

- `chmod ugo-x ~/Library`
- `chmod ugo-x ~/Library/Caches`
- `chmod ugo-x ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm2018.1`

Your perms should look like:

- `~/Library`: `drwx------@`
- `~/Library/Caches`: `drwxr-xr-x`
- `~/Library/Caches/PyCharm2018.1`: `drwxr-xr-x`

I'll bet one of these perms is off.

Notes:

- If you `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm2018.1; touch ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm2018.1` you will get a similar error that will say 'inaccessible' instead of 'invalid'.
- It is safe to delete this file/directory, the cache will be rebuilt on the next application start.

Hope that helps